# Hapi cache engine, I can set but I can't get

Tags: javascript, redis, hapi.js

I using `yar` as my session plugin along with `catbox-redis`.
This is my configurations:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const yar  = require('yar');
const hapiServer = new Hapi.Server({
  cache: {
    engine: require('catbox-redis'),
    host: redisAddress,
    port: redisPort
  }
});

hapiServer.connection({
    host: hapiHostAddress,
    port: hapiPort
});

hapiServer.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/test/{key}/{value}',
  handler: function (request, reply) {

      // In MongoDB, this data will be stored in the
      // "!yar" collection within the "hapi-cache" database.
      var data = {};
      data[request.params.key] = request.params.value;
      request.yar.set('example', data);
      return reply(request.yar.get('example'));
  }
});

const yarOptions = {
    storeBlank: false,
    maxCookieSize: 0,
    cache: {
      expiresIn: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
    cookieOptions: {
        password: 'the-password-must-be-at-least-32-characters-long',
        isSecure: true
    }
};

hapiServer.register({
  register: yar,
  options: yarOptions
}, function (err) {

  // start your hapiServer after plugin registration
  hapiServer.start(function (err) {
    console.log('info', 'Server running at: ' + hapiServer.info.uri)
  })
})
```

The problem is that `request.yar.get('example')` returns the correct data but it doesn't use redis (I'm monitoring redis with `redis-cli monitor`) even though `request.yar.set('example', data)` saves the data to redis.

Comment: Are you sure that `isSecure` isn't an issue for your setup?

Comment: @estus Would it still be set to redis if it was? Redis monitor gives me this on set command: `1480263079.783716 [0 127.0.0.1:39896] "set" "hapi-cache:!yar:8b7efcf2-6b3a-4f16-bdfc-aba2ed0583cf" "{\"item\":{\"example\":{\"test\":\"test\"}},\"stored\":1480263079783,\"ttl\":86400000}"
1480263079.784086 [0 127.0.0.1:39896] "expire" "hapi-cache:!yar:8b7efcf2-6b3a-4f16-bdfc-aba2ed0583cf" "86400"
`

Comment: Not sure about that, it depends on where `isSecure` check is being performed. I would suggest to try it with `isSecure: false`, like it should in dev environment.

Comment: @estus Thanks but it didn't work

Comment: @estus The problem was that cookies were disabled in requestJs